# How to connect to the Django database via a widget encoded in pure Javascript?

Tags: javascript, django

I'm creating an external widget to an existing application that is coded in **Django/Angular**. The widget that i'm coding is in **HTML**, **CSS** and **pure Javascript**.

There is a **REST Django API**. I want to retrieve the data via a fetch.

```
const url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/services';
const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
const headers = new Headers();
headers.append('X-CSRFToken', csrftoken);
const myInit = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: headers,
    mode:'no-cors',
    cache: 'default',
    credentials: 'include'
};

fetch(url, myInit)
    .then(res => {
        res.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    });

function getCookie(name) {
    var value = "; " + document.cookie;
    var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
    if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
}
```

**My problem**: I can't connect to the API, I get a 403 error.

I tried to recover the data via **Insomnia** but it's the same thing, error 403

I also tested in the terminal via http but still the same thing.

```
http http://localhost:8000/api/services/ 'Authorization: Token MyToken'
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Content-Length: 22
Content-Type: text/html
Vary: Origin, Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

<h1>403 Forbidden</h1>
```

Console error:

```
Forbidden (Permission denied): /api/services/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/martin/PycharmProjects/restoratio/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/martin/PycharmProjects/restoratio/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/martin/PycharmProjects/restoratio/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 74, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/martin/PycharmProjects/restoratio/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/martin/PycharmProjects/restoratio/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 114, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/martin/PycharmProjects/restoratio/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rolepermissions/mixins.py", line 14, in dispatch
    (request, *args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/martin/PycharmProjects/restoratio/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rolepermissions/decorators.py", line 28, in wrapper
    raise PermissionDenied
django.core.exceptions.PermissionDenied
HTTP GET /api/services/ 403 [0.01, 127.0.0.1:44192]
```

Comment: You're running the Django application locally apparently, so you should see a more complete error trace in your console (where you launched the Django server) that will give you more information about why the request is forbidden. Please show that error trace.

Comment: So a couple of things. You're using a CSRF token on a `GET` request; you only need CSRF for `POST` requests. Is your endpoint set up to handle `GET` requests? Can you view it through the DRF endpoint browser? Does the endpoint require authorization? What kind of authorization? We'll need to know a lot more about the endpoint in DRF to give a good answer.

Comment: @dirkgroten yes, i have this error in my console: django.core.exceptions.PermissionDenied
HTTP GET /api/services/ 403 [0.00, 127.0.0.1:47388]

Comment: we need the full error trace. you have debug=True? If you're running with `manage.py runserver` you should see a much longer error trace.

Comment: @dirkgroten I edit my question with the console error

Comment: You're using the django `role permissions` package and the view you're calling is decorated with a `@has_role_decorator(role)`. Apparently your user doesn't have the role or isn't seen as authenticated.